# ASP.NET MVC 5 A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'Data.Item'

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting a circular reference error in my ASP.NET MVC Project

Here is the Model

```
public partial class Item
{

    public Item()
    {
        this.Inventories = new HashSet<Inventory>();
        this.PurchasesDetails = new HashSet<PurchasesDetail>();
        this.SalesDetails = new HashSet<SalesDetail>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MeasurementID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal BuyPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal SalePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal CommisionRate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> MftDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ExpDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StockLimit { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }
    public virtual Measurement Measurement { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PurchasesDetail> PurchasesDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SalesDetail> SalesDetails { get; set; }
}
```

And Here is code to get the JSON

```
 db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var items = db.Items.Include(i => i.AspNetUser).Include(i => i.Category).Include(i => i.Measurement).ToList();
        return Json(new { data = items }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I tried with `db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` but it's not working. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem and I tried this

```
var plan_master = from s in db.Plan_Master select s;

        var plans = plan_master.Select(S => new
        {
            S.Plan_ID,
            S.Plan
        });

        return Json(new { data = plans }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

In global.asax put this code for global Json serialization settings :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Try to change following section of code with below:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items, Formatting.None);
    return Json(new { data = json }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I am getting this error

'''Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Self referencing loop detected with type 'Data.Item'. Path '[0].AspNetUser.Items'.'
'''
https://imgur.com/c9nWVq4